# Delayed_job and Prawn scripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, prawn

How do I run **Prawn** scripts with **Delayed_job**.

(Currently using Bj but not supported in Rails3)

This code does not work.

/lib/report_job.rb

```
class ReportJob < Struct.new(:prawn_script_name , :account_id )
      def perform
       bundle exec rails runner "#{Rails.root}/jobs/#{prawn_script_name}.rb #{@current_user.account_id} " 
  end
```

/reports_controller.rb

```
def generate_report(prawn_script_name)
    Delayed::Job.enqueue(ReportJob.new("#{prawn_script_name}.rb","#{@current_user.account_id}"))
end
```

delayed_job table is populated as expected.

```
--- !ruby/struct:ReportJob 
prawn_script_name: statements.rb
account_id: '18' 

Error in last_error field. 
{undefined method `runner' for ReportJob:0xc28f080
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are several misunderstandings here:

- you meant to call runner from outside your app, e.g., in a shell script or command line. in other words, bundle exec rails runner are all commands and arguments of commands, not ruby methods or variables. runner is the first expression that is eval'd inside your perform method, hence your error.
- rails runner just brings up your apps environment and evals the string or path argument given.
- note account_id within the perform task, another mistake in your code I guess.

What you wanted to do could be a simple system call.

It seems your prawn script needs the environment, so simply calling

```
system "ruby #{Rails.root}/jobs/#{prawn_script_name}.rb #{account_id}"
```

won't work.

Now you could surely execute the script with runner from your project directory.

```
system "bundle exec rails runner #{Rails.root}/jobs/#{prawn_script_name}.rb  #{account_id}"
```

but doing this via a system call within your environment is quite redundant. Delayed jobs already have access to your rails environment. so just simply load them.

```
class ReportJob < Struct.new(:prawn_script_name , :account_id )
   def perform
      load "#{Rails.root}/jobs/#{prawn_script_name}.rb"
   end
end
```

hope this helps

Comment: load command works and "runs" the prawn script. However, I need to pass arguments to the prawn scripts e.g.account_id to scope the data for the pdf reports. This is my next hurdle to overcome.

Comment: can you not work your various scripts into a class and a method call? where are these scripts from and can they not be generalized?